# Parameterised Query to Oracle in ADO Crashes Excel

Tags: oracle, excel, vba, odbc, ado

I have set up a parameterised query, using ADO 2.7 inside Excel 2007. The database connection is made via ODBC and every attempt at executing the query results in Excel crashing...and when I say 'crashing', I mean it has to close and restart!

At first I thought this was a problem with my query being too long (involving multiple parameters); but I tried a very basic, single parameter, query and had the same problem... This is using positional/unnamed parameters, so perhaps that's the problem; but I'm not sure if I can use named parameters with an Oracle query unless I wrap it up in a stored function in the schema.

My code, for what it's worth:

**Open the Database** (`DBConnection` is a custom type with `DSN`, `Username`, `xPassword` and `Key` members, the password is stored in memory with rudimentary encryption; there is a corresponding `dbClose` function, which I omit here.)

```
Private Function dbOpen(ByRef db As ADODB.Connection, Creds As DBConnection) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    Set db = New ADODB.Connection
    db.Open Creds.DSN, Creds.Username, XorC(Creds.xPassword, Creds.Key)

    If db.State <> adStateOpen Then dbOpen = False Else dbOpen = True
End Function
```

**Get Data** (Simplified, with one parameter, for sake of example.)

```
Public Function GetData(ODBC As DBConnection, myParam As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim myDB As ADODB.Connection
    Dim myQuery As ADODB.Command
    Dim Parameter As ADODB.Parameter

    Set myDB = New ADODB.Connection

    If dbOpen(myDB, ODBC) Then
        Set myQuery = New ADODB.Command
        myQuery.ActiveConnection = myDB
        myQuery.CommandText = "select * from sometable where id = ?"

        Set Parameter = myQuery.CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 5, myParam)

        Set GetData = myQuery.Execute

        dbClose myDB
    Else
        MsgBox "Cannot connect to the database.", vbExclamation
        Set GetData = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

**Testing routine that will crash Excel**

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim Connection As DBConnection
    Dim myData As ADODB.Recordset

    With Connection
        .DSN = "myDSN"
        .Username = "dbUser"
        .Key = Now
        .xPassword = XorC("p4s5w0rd", .Key)
    End With

    Set myData = GetData(Connection, "AB123")  ' Crashes here
    dbClose myData
End Sub
```

Comment: You're not adding the parameter you create to the Command object:  "myQuery.Parameters.Append Parameter"   Just creating it doesn't add it...

Comment: Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not adding the parameter you create to the Command object:

```
myQuery.Parameters.Append Parameter
```

Just creating it doesn't add it...